# How to make half of svg transparent?

Tags: html, css, svg

I made a simple svg with Adobe xd.

```
    <svg width="1366" height="667" viewBox="0 0 1366 667" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <path d="M257.992 530.241C129.811 537.919 32.5885 624.613 0 667H1366V0C1327.98 6.39808 1225.87 44.1468 1121.59 143.957C1017.3 243.767 895.278 275.117 847.3 278.317C716.946 278.317 657.201 331.101 570.298 407.878C483.396 484.655 418.219 520.644 257.992 530.241Z" fill="#2723DE" fill-opacity="0.8"/>
</svg>
```

https://codepen.io/v7193m/pen/dypbJVN
As you can see, It has a path but svg covers the whole screen.So, is there any way to make the white part, transparent to put some text? (I know that i could write my text in XD and export all of them, but I want to know it is posbble to do something like that or not.)

[this is what i want to do, all the text should be in svg.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eNHs4.jpg)

Comment: But the white part is transparent!

Comment: but I cant put any tag there!

Comment: I edited the post and putan image to show what I mean.

Comment: I see no text in the example i.e. the image does show what you want to achieve but there's no text in your codepen that might produce that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put your text into a div which is positioned absolute. That means it wont alter the position of the svg coming after it.

As your svg is in fact transparent on the left/top you don't need to move the text on top of it, but if the svg had say white there then you'd need to give the text div a higher z-index, to bring it forward towards the reader.

Here's the snippet:

```css
svg {
  position: relative;
}
.mytext {
  position: absolute;
  top:0;
  left: 0;
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 3em;
  /*and any formatting ofyour text that  you want */
}
```

```html
<div class="mytext">My text</div>
 <svg width="1366" height="667" viewBox="0 0 1366 667" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <path d="M257.992 530.241C129.811 537.919 32.5885 624.613 0 667H1366V0C1327.98 6.39808 1225.87 44.1468 1121.59 143.957C1017.3 243.767 895.278 275.117 847.3 278.317C716.946 278.317 657.201 331.101 570.298 407.878C483.396 484.655 418.219 520.644 257.992 530.241Z" fill="#2723DE" fill-opacity="0.8"/>
</svg>
```